# python contextlib closing prevents enter/exit calls

Tags: python, python-3.x, contextmanager

Most likely I don't understand this fully but I have a class declared like

```
class db:
    def __init__(self, name):
        pass
        #self._conn = get_conn(name)
    
    def __enter__(self):
        print('enter')
        #self_conn.begin_transaction()
    def __exit__(self, a, b, c):
        print('exit')
        #self._conn.commit()
    def close(self):
        print('close')
        #self._conn.close()
```

When I use it like:

```
with db('bname') as db:
    print('do something')
```

I get the expected output like:

```
enter
do something
exit
```

but when I use contextlib closing those functions don't get called at all

```
from contextlib import closing

with closing(db('bname')) as db:
    print('do something')
```

I only get:

```
do something
close
```

My understanding was the contextlib closing can be used with context manager classes to call `close` always but what am i missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `closing` class implements its own version of `__exit__`. This calls `close()`.

Since you're passing an instance of `closing` to the `with` block, the `__exit__` method of the closing instance will get called and not yours.

Subclass the `closing` class for your `__exit__` to get called. Here's an example:

```py
from contextlib import closing


class Db(closing):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(self)
        print('initializing')

    def close(self):
        print('closing')

    def __enter__(self):
        print('entering')

    def __exit__(self, *exc_info):
        print('exiting')
        return super().__exit__(*exc_info)


with Db() as db:
    print('running')
```

Output

```
initializing
entering
running
exiting
closing
```

Comment: Thanks, how do I subclass `closing`? I have seen it being used in many places but never with subclassing

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify why we need to `return super()__exit__(*exc_info)` from derived exit?

Comment: @user642770 Without calling the superclass method, your close function won't get called.

Answer (score 1):

It is the [`with` statement](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) that executes the `__enter__` and `__exit__` blocks. In your second example, you are applying in on the `closing` function, not on your `db` class. That's why those methods don't get triggered.

Comment: So there is no way to make them both work? I have seen `closing` being use a lot with `with` statements (for e.g. with file open), how does that work?